# Query taking long time with DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Access 2003.  One form in my project takes a long time to appear to  users.

This is the applicable query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb_KonzeptDaten.DFCC
,tb_KonzeptDaten.OBD_Code AS Konzept_Obd
,tb_bauteile.*
,FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.VAG_Code
,FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code
,FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.F_Klasse_EU
,FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.F_Klasse_US
,FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.CDT AS CdtNr
,FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Pfad_Bezeichnung
,FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad AS PfadName
,FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerunterpfad
,tb_bauteile_Tools.Tool AS Tool_
FROM (
    (
        tb_bauteile LEFT JOIN FehlerCodes_akt_Liste ON tb_bauteile.OBD2_Plaus = FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.ID
        ) LEFT JOIN tb_bauteile_Tools ON tb_bauteile.Tool = tb_bauteile_Tools.ID
    )
LEFT JOIN tb_KonzeptDaten ON FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad = tb_KonzeptDaten.DFC;
```

If I delete **DISTINCT** and then run the query, the performance will be improved
(from 9 seconds to 2 seconds).  In addition, I put an index on the neccessary fields as well.

How can I change my query(maybe without DISTINCT) to improve the performance?

Comment: try group by instead and tell me the result please

Comment: Where are the duplicate records coming from? Do they exist in the main table (tb_KonzeptDaten) or are they due to the joins?

Comment: @Remou I'm not sur if I got your question correctly, but if I delete **Distinct** value of two column(DFCC,Konzept_obd) duplicate in the result that both of them are from**tb_KonzeptDaten** table, with **DISTINCT** I don't see any value in these two column

Comment: @levaniev I tried to use **Group BY** but an error occured and said:Cannot group on fields selected with '*'

Comment: When you look at the tables without a query, are there duplicates? Which table is the biggest?

Comment: tb_konzepz is bigger than the others with 35000 records and , yes I see duplicate in this table, for example I have 9 DFCC with the value of 898 and exactly I see 9 DFCC with the value of 898 in the result query without **DISTINCT**

Comment: Okay, start from there. Create a query `SELECT DISTINCT DFCC,
OBD_Code AS Konzept_Obd FROM tb_KonzeptDaten`, save the query and use that query instead of tb_KonzeptDaten in this query. If it runs faster, you can substitute a derived table for the query. Also, have you made sure that you have suitable indexes?

Comment: Remou, thank you so much  for you helps, I did it and I tested the query, which you have said.Intressting, the run time of the query didn't change. YES I think I use Suitable indexes

Comment: and I think I can't use **GROUP BY** bucause I dont have any summation or... in my Query,What do you mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15049/discussion-between-remou-and-kabi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest get distinct ids and then in column query get your desired columns.

something like this

```
Select (select Fehlerpfad from FehlerCodes_akt_Liste where id=A.id ) as col1, ...
from
(
   Select distinct ids from table
   .........
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of distinct is essentially doing a `group by` so you only get "unique" records.  If you don't have any duplicate records then this is not needed.

I would place my focus on your joins, instead of the `distinct` clause.

Comment: I have duplicate record i.e with **Distinct** this query returns me c.a 3000 records but without **Distinct** c.a 15000. I 've change my **Left Join** into **INNER JOIN**, the performance has benn improved but only one second. Have you a better idea?