# Improving the SQL query response time

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

I'm using access 2003 and I have a query in my project which is very very slow ( to retrieve 3800 records it needs 10 seconds) It looks like this:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT tb_KonzeptDaten.DFCC, 
          tb_KonzeptDaten.OBD_Code AS Konzept_Obd,tb_bauteile.*, 
          FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.VAG_Code, 
          FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code,
          FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.F_Klasse_EU, 
          FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.F_Klasse_US, 
          FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.CDT AS CdtNr,
          FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Pfad_Bezeichnung, 
          FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.
          Fehlerpfad AS PfadName, 
          FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerunterpfad, 
          tb_bauteile_Tools.Tool AS Tool_
FROM     (
              (tb_bauteile 
                     LEFT JOIN FehlerCodes_akt_Liste 
                          ON tb_bauteile.OBD2_Plaus=FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.ID
               ) 
               LEFT JOIN tb_bauteile_Tools 
                     ON tb_bauteile.Tool=tb_bauteile_Tools.ID)
               LEFT JOIN tb_KonzeptDaten 
                      ON FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad = tb_KonzeptDaten.DFC;
```

But

If I delete two first field (tb_KonzeptDaten.DFCC, tb_KonzeptDaten.OBD_Code AS Konzept_Obd) then the query works fine

My question is now:

How can I change the my first query to improve the performance?

Comment: Do you have to have DISTINCT? It is slow. Have you got indexes on all relevant keys?

Comment: yes Romou, I have indexes on nessecary fields

Comment: Seems to be the second asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859191/query-taking-long-time-with-distinct

Comment: YEs Romu, but I found some new things I wanted to use our chat but it's blocked

Comment: Using the DISTINCT predicate requires that the tables perform a full table scan without the aide of indexing.  Why are you using DISTINCT?  If it is because you have duplicate records as mentioned in the previous question, you have 'dirty' data, and that's something that should be corrected.